# <div> not displaying after clicking the button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was expecting that after hitting the button, the `<div id="dni">` would show up, however nothing is changing. What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function show_dni(){
                $("#dni").toggle();
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="show_dni()">Ver cliente</button>
            <div id="dni" class="hidden">
                DNI: <input type="text" name="id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Oddly, this same code works as intended on Fidd http://jsfiddle.net/wmL1zt7L/

Comment: Have you involved jquery library at header

Comment: @kannan yes, it is... ok this is odd, just tried this one fidd and it's working... http://jsfiddle.net/wmL1zt7L/

Answer (score 2):

Hey here is an example of how to use it.
https://jsfiddle.net/se4er462/

I think that in your class you used visibility property instead of display.
while toggle change the display between none to block, and vice verse

The correct class:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Edit / Addition:

The bootstrap hidden class define the element visibilty as

```
.hidden{
   display:none!important;
}
```

Therefore, the toggle functionality won't be able to change it. If the display was without the important, the toggle would've worked.

Comment: my code also works in fiddle.. :S `.hidden` is not "my class", it's from bootstrap

Comment: if it's from bootstrap then it's should be like 
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
therefore it should work, can you add your entire html?

Comment: I just copied your code and it works for me, maybe you have some cache loaded, try running it through incognito

Comment: yea, it worked because it had the `style="display:none;"`, Try now that I changed back to `class="hidden"` as it's intended to be.

Comment: This is a good one, because of the class display is important the toggle won't change it visibility because bootstrap overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery and Bootstrap's hidden class, I managed to get the same effect using Bootstrap's collapse class.

```
<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dni">Ver cliente</button>
    <div id="dni" class="collapse">
        DNI: <input type="text" name="id">
    </div>
</div>
```